# Deno mock out named import in unit test

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, testing, deno

I would like to make an unit test for a module that is using `jsonfile` to read the data.

```
import * as jsonfile from 'https://deno.land/x/jsonfile/mod.ts'
```

would like to mock out the jsonfile.readJsonSync to return the test data and avoid writing to disk. Can this be done?

Hope this abstract example describes what I want to archive:

> index.ts

```
import * as jsonfile from 'https://deno.land/x/jsonfile/mod.ts'

export function readAndReturn() {
  return jsonfile.readJsonSync('./example.json')
}
```

> index.test.ts

```
import { assertEquals } from 'https://deno.land/std@0.112.0/testing/asserts.ts'
import { readAndReturn } from './index.ts'


const dataFixture = {hello: "word"} 
// mock out jsonfile.readJsonSync to return dataFixture and not the actual file content

Deno.test("Reads the data", () => {
  assertEquals(readAndReturn(), dataFixture)
})
```

---

## Solution

A huge thanks to @mfulton26 and @jsejcksn for pointing me in the right direction.

> unit.test.importmap.json

```json
{
  "imports": {
    "https://deno.land/x/jsonfile/mod.ts": "./mocks/jsonfile.ts"
  }
}
```

> mocks/jsonfile.ts

```js
import sinon from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/sinon@11.1.2?dts'

const readJsonSync = sinon.stub()
const writeJsonSync = sinon.stub()

export { readJsonSync, writeJsonSync }
```

> index.test.ts

```js
import { readJsonSync as readJsonSyncMock } from './mocks/jsonfile.ts'

Deno.test(
  'Reads the data', () => {
    const data = ["hello world"]
    readJsonSyncMock.withArgs(`./example.json`).returns(data)
    assertEquals(readAndReturn(), data)
  }
)
```

```sh
deno test --import-map=unit.test.importmap.json
```

Comment: Are you asking for a recommendation module for mocking in tests in Deno, or something else? What exactly is the question?

Comment: Let me update my question to make it more clear :)

Comment: Is it more clear now @jsejcksn ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ES modules cannot be stubbed.

You can however wrap the functionality you want to stub in a class or object and export that and then you can stub methods on it using [Sinon.JS](https://sinonjs.org/) or other libraries.

For getting started with Sinon.JS in Deno I suggest checking out [Integration with testing libraries | Testing | Manual | Deno](https://deno.land/manual/testing#integration-with-testing-libraries) which references a [sinon_example.ts](https://deno.land/std@0.112.0/testing/sinon_example.ts).

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. Tried the @jsejcksn suggestion and realised that I would hit the problem you pointed out in the comment.

Answer (score 4):

You can substitute modules using an [import map](https://deno.land/manual/linking_to_external_code/import_maps).

Just create a local module `./jsonfile.mock.ts` containing your mocked functions and export them using the same names as the real module at `https://deno.land/x/jsonfile/mod.ts`. Then, create an import map with the correct mapping and use it when you run your test:

`./jsonfile.mock.ts`:

```ts
export function readJsonSync (filePath: string): unknown {
  // implement mocked fn
}

// and any other imports you use from the module
```

`./index.importmap.json`:

```json
{
  "imports": {
    "https://deno.land/x/jsonfile/mod.ts": "./jsonfile.mock.ts"
  }
}
```

```
deno test --import-map=index.importmap.json index.test.ts
```

Comment: I like this solution a lot. It does mean creating potentially lots of different mock files and import maps throughout a codebase and it might require running `deno test` multiple times for different subset of tests that require different mocks but this is nice just the same. Too bad there isn't a feature in Deno for specifying a custom import map per test file... 

Comment: @mfulton26 It's simple enough to write a test runner script which will pickup these files based on name and run them all, but I agree: the ecosystem could benefit from a solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This seems like a solution that would work for me. Just have to figure out know if I should write my own spy or use some lib like `sinon` to assert what `writeJsonSync` was called with.

Comment: realised I can't spy on it because the `importmap` will cause a circular dependency. But then again I also wish to avoid writing to the disk (just ended writing a unit test that does it and cleans up while I was waiting for help)

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping your module with another module might work in some cases, but if your module has side effects with errors in them, this won't work.

I've created a small module to get around this issue: [Fake Imports](https://deno.land/x/fake_imports).

It might not be possible to mock static imports, but dynamic imports certainly can be mocked!

### Usage

```js
import { Importer } from "https://deno.land/x/fake_imports/mod.js";
const importer = new Importer(import.meta.url);

importer.fakeModule("https://deno.land/x/jsonfile/mod.ts", `
function readJsonSync() {}
export {readJsonSync};
`);

// Then load your main module asynchronously
const mainModule = await importer.import("./main.ts");
// And perform your test on mainModule like you usually would
```

Comment: Thx for chipping in Jesper , it's good to have a some alternatives and hopefully it will be easier in the future of native deno.