# How to spy and assert non exported methods

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, deno, spy

I've created a script that receives JSON data from a file, parses it, reformats and groups em and then returns an aggregated table, which I am trying to write tests for.

```
The code structure

├── Readme.md
├── input.json
├── main.ts
├── services
│   ├── calculateTransactionTotals.js
│   └── validateInput.js
└── tests
    ├── mocks.js
    └── tests.test.js
```

```js
// main.js
import { validateInput, readInputFile } from './services/validateInput.js'
import { calculateTransactionTotals } from './services/calculateTransactionTotals.js'

validateInput()

const content = await readInputFile()

calculateTransactionTotals(content)
```

```js
// calculateTransactionTotals

import groupby from 'https://esm.sh/lodash.groupby'
import moment from 'https://esm.sh/moment'

export function calculateTransactionTotals(content) {
  groupTransactionsByUserAndCurrency(content) // omitting this for brevity, basically does a bunch of `groupby`s
  prepareData(groupTransactionsByUserAndCurrency(content), content)
}

function prepareData(transactionsGroupedByUserIdAndCurrency, content) {
  const result = {}
  // some logic here, doesnt matter
  printTable(result)
  return result
}

function printTable(result) {
  console.table(result, ['GBP', 'EUR', 'USD', 'last-activity'])
}

export const _internals = { prepareData }
```

My main idea is to run `calculateTransactionTotals` and assert `prepareData` was run and returned the expected value. But I'm struggling to get the `spy` to run.

```js
import { calculateTransactionTotals, _internals } from '../services/calculateTransactionTotals.js'
import data from './mocks.js'
import { assertSpyCalls, spy } from 'https://deno.land/std@0.158.0/testing/mock.ts'

Deno.test('is the expected result returned', () => {
  const prepareDataSpy = spy(_internals, 'prepareData')
  calculateTransactionTotals(data)
  assertSpyCalls(prepareDataSpy, 1)
})
```

Any other proposals on how to test this functionality would be welcome and accepted as a correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, some contextual observations:

In the module `services/calculateTransactionTotals.js` you have defined and exported a function `calculateTransactionTotals`. In the same module, you've defined a function `prepareData` which is not directly exported. However, you have exported an object named `_internals` which references the `prepareData` function on a property by the same name (making it a method).

The function `calculateTransactionTotals` contains an internal, direct reference to the function `prepareData`, which makes it a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures):

```js
export function calculateTransactionTotals(content) {
  groupTransactionsByUserAndCurrency(content) // omitting this for brevity, basically does a bunch of `groupby`s
  prepareData(groupTransactionsByUserAndCurrency(content), content)
}
```

This function reference is immutable. Spying on it does not replace it in the ES module graph.

The way that the [`spy`](https://deno.land/std@0.158.0/testing/mock.ts?source#L314) function works is to create and return a **new** "spy" function which is essentially a proxy to (or "wrapper" around) the original. In the case of a [spied method](https://deno.land/std@0.158.0/testing/mock.ts?source#L221), it also [overwrites the method property on the target object](https://deno.land/std@0.158.0/testing/mock.ts?source#L287).

---

The example you provided has quite a bit of code which is unrelated to the problem, so I'll create a minimal, reproducible example below in order to keep the focus on the problematic code:

`mod.ts`:

```ts
// prepareData
function privateFn() {}

// calculateTransactionTotals
export function publicFn() {
  privateFn();
}

export const _internals = { privateFn };
```

`mod.test.ts`:

```ts
import {
  assertSpyCalls,
  spy,
} from "https://deno.land/std@0.158.0/testing/mock.ts";
import { _internals, publicFn } from "./mod.ts";

Deno.test("private function is invoked once", () => {
  const spyFn = spy(_internals, "privateFn");
  publicFn();
  assertSpyCalls(spyFn, 1);
});
```

When running the test (copied from the code in your question), this is the output:

```
% deno test
Check file:///Users/deno/so-73911434/mod.test.ts
running 1 test from ./mod.test.ts
private function is invoked once ... FAILED (10ms)

 ERRORS 

private function is invoked once => ./mod.test.ts:7:6
error: AssertionError: spy not called as much as expected:


    [Diff] Actual / Expected


-   0
+   1

    throw new AssertionError(message);
          ^
    at assertSpyCalls (https://deno.land/std@0.158.0/testing/mock.ts:489:11)
    at file:///Users/deno/so-73911434/mod.test.ts:10:3

 FAILURES 

private function is invoked once => ./mod.test.ts:7:6

FAILED | 0 passed | 1 failed (60ms)

error: Test failed
```

When the `privateFn` method is spied on in the test, that doesn't update the internal reference to `privateFn` in the `publicFn` closure, which is your testing goal.

In order to do that, you'll need to reference `privateFn` as a method on the `_internals` object instead, like this:

`mod.ts`:

```ts
function privateFn() {}

export const _internals = { privateFn };

export function publicFn() {
  // Now invoking a method on `_internals`:
  _internals.privateFn();
}
```

Now, when the test is run, the spy call replaces the method property with the spy, and the spy function is invoked by `publicFn` (instead of the original function):

```
% deno test
Check file:///Users/deno/so-73911434/mod.test.ts
running 1 test from ./mod.test.ts
private function is invoked once ... ok (8ms)

ok | 1 passed | 0 failed (48ms)
```

One last note:

Be sure to reverse your spy mutation after you're finished, so that the original object is restored to its former state. This means adding one more line in the example test:

`mod.test.ts`:

```ts
import {
  assertSpyCalls,
  spy,
} from "https://deno.land/std@0.158.0/testing/mock.ts";
import { _internals, publicFn } from "./mod.ts";

Deno.test("private function is invoked once", () => {
  const spyFn = spy(_internals, "privateFn");
  publicFn();
  assertSpyCalls(spyFn, 1);
  // Restore the original method to its property on the `_internals` object:
  spyFn.restore();
});
```

Comment: thank you. I was told to reference `  _internals.privateFn();` in my code to be able to spy it but I just found that adapting one's code to be able to write unit tests on them maybe isnt such a good idea conceptualy. (the _internals was just an attempt I did to be able to spy it)
Ultimately I feel directly exporting the 'private' method is more straightforward, WDYT?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73911434/how-to-spy-and-assert-non-exported-methods/73912219?noredirect=1#comment130509563_73912219) @GeorgeKatsanos You can export the private function, but the core problem is that the public function (closure) in your original code references an immutable function directly. If you need to mock a function call in a closure like this, a better way would be to export it from another module and create a mock module for that one, loading it through an import map in your test. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69683323/438273) for that.

Comment: would refactoring into a Class with methods make testing easier on that regard?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73911434/how-to-spy-and-assert-non-exported-methods/73912219?noredirect=1#comment130512565_73912219) @GeorgeKatsanos A class instance is just an object — so, yes, you can spy on a class instance's methods.

Comment: unless they're private I guess https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields